# Excel Online - Replicate date from sheet1 columnA to sheet2 columnB

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Online, using dropbox excel online, I have a sheet opened named:

> Product Nice

On that sheet, among others, I have two columns with a range of 30 values, and I wish to create an NEW sheet, containing ONLY those two columns range values.

I have tried, on my *new sheet*, on a given cell formula to place:

`="Product Nice"!b1` (just one cell to test it out) - **Result: fail;**

Also

```
="Product Nice".A3
```

(again, just one cell for testing) - **Result: fail;**

Also:

```
=INDIRECT("Product Nice", "!A3")
```

(here getting VALUE!)

Can I have some help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single quotes, just the same as in off-line excel:

`='Product Nice'!B1`

Comment: It worked! Tk! Do you care to tell me how can we, instead of a single cell, see the values all cells in a given column?

Comment: You need to enter formula to all cells.